# Android Studio not recognizing Java Version when attempting a course

Tags: java, kotlin, android-studio

I am trying to complete the Kotlin Koans course on Android Studio, but I cannot even begin because it is not accepting my version of java as valid. After I select my JDK, the error it gives me is: "Failed to determine Java version from string: Oracle OpenJDK version 21. In the settings section, choose or download another JDK.". When I allow Android Studio to download another JDK, it gives me the same error. I downloaded the newest version of both Android Studio and JDK earlier today. Is there any way to resolve this?